# Fat Free Framework returns 404 error with custom routes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fat-free-framework

I am trying to set up Fat Free Framework on [Z-Wamp](http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/) server.
At first I tried to edit the home page trying to understand how templates work, but when I try to add a second route I get a 404 error.

I've already read similar questions here, but none of these seemed to help.

These are my routes (only `/stats` doesn't work):

```
$f3->route('GET /',
           function() use ($f3) {
               $f3->set('page','ui/pages/idx.htm');
               echo Template::instance()->render('ui/template.htm');
           }
          );

$f3->route('GET /stats',
          function(){
              echo 'Stats';
          }
         );
```

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(lib|tmp)\/|\.(ini|php)$ - [R=404]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

And this is my `httpd.conf` configuration for root folder

```
<Directory />
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Of course `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

The same files work on my production website.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `RewriteBase` directive?

Comment: Are you sure, you're not getting any error messages on the console? Is your project in a sub folder?

Comment: @sascha no errors and my project is in the root folder.

Comment: Weird. Do you have a folder named `stats`?

Comment: What does return the 404? Apache or F3?

Comment: @xfra35 I don't have any folder named `stats` and the 404 error is returned by Apache.

Comment: Ok I got it: remove `php` from the first line => `RewriteRule ^(lib|tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]`. It prevents `index.php` from being run!

Comment: @xfra35 it finally works! That line was in the default F3 .htaccess file, so I never suspected that it might have been the cause!

Comment: Yeah that was tricky. It was removed from the [dev version](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/dev/.htaccess) but has not been published yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to remove `php` from the first `RewriteRule` because it prevents `index.php` from being run!

It should be:

```
RewriteRule ^(lib|tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]
```

This line was added by mistake on F3's master repository. It was removed in [dev version](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/dev/.htaccess) and should be removed from master soon now.

Comment: Thanks again, I lost two days trying to understanding what was wrong!